# WkWebView does not rotate video in full screen?

Tags: ios, swift, video, wkwebview

I am using `WkWebView` to play a video in full screen. (iOS10)

I set the following value in code, while my iPhone's rotation lock is turned off:

```
videoWebView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

However, when my phone is tilted horizontally, the video doesn't rotate at all, just stayed in portrait view.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use autoresizing mask if you use constraints. Your view should stick to the screen-edges without any extra-piece of code. Furthermore, if this view's flag `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` doesn't set to `true`, your code doesn't affect at all.

Specify portrait and landscape orientations for the application instead. You can do that in the project settings